# sonar scanner error "Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor"

Tags: java, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube, sonarscanner

Team,
my same steps locally from MacBook work fine and when I built the same in shell script and invoked from Jenkins pipeline I get this error. any hint is it permission related because am setting Jenkins as USER in docker file? or is it bug? no clue. any hint?

`sonar-scanner ${SONAR_PROJECT_KEY} ${CODE_PATH} ${SONAR_HOST_URL} ${SONAR_TOKEN} ${SONAR_PROJECT_NAME}`

```
echo "Running Sonar Setup"
Running Sonar Setup
sonar-scanner --version
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 4.7.0.2747
INFO: Java 11.0.14.1 Eclipse Adoptium (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 5.4.0-65-generic amd64
```

Jenkins log

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 4.7.0.2747
INFO: Java 11.0.14.1 Eclipse Adoptium (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 5.4.0-65-generic amd64
INFO: User cache: /home/jenkins/.sonar/cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 9.2.4
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "US-ASCII" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=537ms
INFO: Server id: C00CED92-AWlyCvw4VSvNnYFw3U2r
INFO: User cache: /home/jenkins/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=243ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=40489ms
INFO: Loaded core extensions: developer-scanner
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Process project properties (done) | time=6ms
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Project key: AIgroup_product_Main
INFO: Base dir: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/product/code-coverage-WIP
INFO: Working dir: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/product/code-coverage-WIP/.scannerwork
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'AIgroup_product_Main'
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'AIgroup_product_Main' (done) | time=222ms
INFO: Load project branches
INFO: Load project branches (done) | time=217ms
INFO: Load project pull requests
INFO: Load project pull requests (done) | time=214ms
INFO: Load branch configuration
INFO: Load branch configuration (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Auto-configuring with CI 'Jenkins'
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=450ms
INFO: Auto-configuring with CI 'Jenkins'
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=8916ms
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO: 49659 files indexed...  (last one was bazel-code-coverage-WIP/src/ui/labeling/apps/mapgt-validator/src/app/routed/jobs/job/job.component.ts)
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=218ms
INFO: 86490 files indexed...  (last one was bazel-code-coverage-WIP/external/com_github_gogo_protobuf/protoc-gen-gogo/Makefile)
WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/product/code-coverage-WIP/bazel-code-coverage-WIP/external/com_google_protobuf/php/src/GPBMetadata/Google/Protobuf/Type.php at line 21 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
WARN: Invalid character encountered in file /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/product/code-coverage-WIP/bazel-code-coverage-WIP/external/com_google_protobuf/php/src/GPBMetadata/Google/Protobuf/Api.php at line 21 for encoding US-ASCII. Please fix file content or configure the encoding to be used using property 'sonar.sourceEncoding'.
INFO: 125923 files indexed...  (last one was bazel-code-coverage-WIP/devops/terraform/live/product-sjc4/product-dev0-sjc4.nonprod-nvkong.com/modules/hl-accessmanagement/rds.tf)
INFO: 152919 files indexed...  (last one was bazel-code-coverage-WIP/bazel-out/host/bin/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/hash/sha256.runfiles/product/external/python3_9_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/python3.9/lib2to3/fixes/fix_funcattrs.py)
INFO: 188294 files indexed...  (last one was bazel-out/host/bin/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/hash/sha256.runfiles/product/external/python3_9_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/locators.py)
INFO: 192531 files indexed
INFO: Quality profile for c: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for cpp: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for css: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for go: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for java: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for js: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for json: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for kotlin: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for objc: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for php: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for plsql: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for py: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for ruby: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for scala: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for swift: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for terraform: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for ts: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for web: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for yaml: Sonar way
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module AIgroup_product_Main_Project
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 2:44.377s
INFO: Final Memory: 8M/120M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:66)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:282)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:79)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:384)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:380)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:349)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorExtensionDictionnary
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:66)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorContext
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:66)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.sensor.DefaultSensorStorage
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:66)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.sensor.DefaultSensorStorage
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:66)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.containers.ImmutablePicoContainer.getComponent(ImmutablePicoContainer.java:40)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:718)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.measure.DefaultMetricFinder
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:66)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.repository.MetricsRepository
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:66)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.repository.MetricsRepository
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:66)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.containers.ImmutablePicoContainer.getComponent(ImmutablePicoContainer.java:40)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:718)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load metrics
    at org.sonar.scanner.repository.DefaultMetricsRepositoryLoader.load(DefaultMetricsRepositoryLoader.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.repository.MetricsRepositoryProvider.provide(MetricsRepositoryProvider.java:36)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request url: http://sonar.company.com:9119/api/metrics/search?ps=500&p=1
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:205)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:124)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:111)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.DefaultScannerWsClient.call(DefaultScannerWsClient.java:73)
    at org.sonar.scanner.repository.DefaultMetricsRepositoryLoader.loadFromPaginatedWs(DefaultMetricsRepositoryLoader.java:57)
    at org.sonar.scanner.repository.DefaultMetricsRepositoryLoader.load(DefaultMetricsRepositoryLoader.java:45)
    ... 123 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okio.SocketAsyncTimeout.newTimeoutException(JvmOkio.kt:143)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.access$newTimeoutException(AsyncTimeout.kt:162)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:335)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.kt:427)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:320)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.HeadersReader.readLine(HeadersReader.kt:29)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:178)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.OkHttpClientBuilder.addHeaders(OkHttpClientBuilder.java:222)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:203)
    ... 128 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at okio.InputStreamSource.read(JvmOkio.kt:90)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:129)
    ... 148 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[Pipeline] }
```

DOCKERFILE running this

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  build-essential \
  ca-certificates \
  curl \
  dnsutils \
  g++ \
  gcc \
  git \
  openjdk-11-jdk-headless \
  python \
  python-dev \
  python-pkg-resources \
  python-setuptools \
  python3 \
  python3-dev \
  python3-pip \
  python3-pkg-resources \
  python3-setuptools \
  software-properties-common \
  unzip \
  wget \
  zip \
  zlib1g-dev \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && apt-get clean

RUN mkdir /downloads/sonarqube -p
RUN cd /downloads/sonarqube 
RUN wget https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.7.0.2747-linux.zip
RUN unzip sonar-scanner-cli-4.7.0.2747-linux.zip
RUN mv sonar-scanner-4.7.0.2747-linux /opt/sonar-scanner
ENV PATH="$PATH:/opt/sonar-scanner/bin"
RUN rm /sonar-scanner-cli-4.7.0.2747-linux.zip
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash jenkins
USER jenkins
WORKDIR /home/jenkins
```